# PCB on/off switch

Tags: power-supply, pcb, switches, switching

I'm looking for a PCB on/off 2-position switch like this (this comes from a [Roland TR09](https://static.roland.com/assets/images/products/gallery/tr-09_rear_gal.jpg)):

[image]

All switches that I usually find are 0.3A max, and I'm looking for a 1A switch.

**What's the exact english name for such a switch?**

**Do PCB switches like this exist in 1A?** (I couldn't find any, anywhere, but perhaps I'm looking in the wrong categories of suppliers?).

Comment: I don't know what "1A" is.

Comment: I think that's a current specification, not a location for "in".

Comment: @pjc50 a night of rest for me. Right now. Doh.

Comment: I have voted to reopen. This seems primarily as a terminology question (name of this type switch), not a shopping question.

Comment: @DoxyLover, indeed it was a terminology question, because I was lost when searching on suppliers' websites, when there was many thousands of answers for "switch". That's why I was looking for a more specific name.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 1A is a current specification indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Not overly surprising (English isn't my first language, so I had to think for a second), this is called a "Slide Switch".

Mouser has a [category](http://eu.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Switches/Slide-Switches/_/N-5g2x/) with some 3·10³ of those.

Comment: Thank you very much. About terminology: what's the name for an "angle switch"? i.e. the pins **not** under the switch (like [this](http://www.mouser.fr/images/nkkswitches/images/nkk_cs12anw03.jpg)) but the pins 90° angle from the switch (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiTOI.jpg)). [I can't find the relevant name here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D7QD.jpg).

Comment: @Basj Right-angle slide switch.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I searched [here](http://eu.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Switches/Slide-Switches/_/N-5g2x/) but didn't find under this name. It seems that there is [no category for right-angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D7QD.jpg).

Comment: @Basj Look under the "Termination style" column.